# Spring - Order of Bean-Creation defined in Security-Configurations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

In a Spring-Boot and Spring-Security application, I have two Security-Configurations. So two classes that are annotated with `@Configuration` and 
`@EnableWebSecurity` and extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

In Configuration one, let's just call it foo, I create two beans (annotated with `@Bean`). Both beans are AuthenticationProvider's. One of them is marked with `@Primary` and `@ConditionalOnProperty`. It replaces the other authentication provider if some property is set, for testing purposes.

In the other Configuration, let's call it bar, I request one of these AuthenticationProviders by having an `@Autowired` annotated field of type AuthenticationProvider.

I have annotated the foo-Configuration with `@Order(1)` to indicate that it should run first. bar-Configuration has `@Order(2)`. However, the application cannot start this way. Spring tells me that it cannot create the bar-configuration because the requested AuthenticationProvider-bean is still under creation. This confuses me. I thought the the foo-Configuration should already have been created, because it has a higher Order-priority? Why is the bean still not available?

If I annotate the bar-Configuration with `@DependsOn("fooConfiguration")`then it works. But I don't really understand why. Also: Is the usage of `@DependsOn` code-smell and is what I am doing unorthodox (injecting a bean of one configuration into another)?

Comment: Not sure if `@Order` is used for configurations. Have you looked at `@AutoConfigureBefore` and `@AutoConfigureAfter`?

Comment: @Mike Hey, thanks for your input! I am very sure that this annotation is used for Configurations, it's usage is recommended in many resources that I have read on the internet and I have personally already seen it work on security-configurations. It's vital if you want to have multiple configurations that need to configure filter-chains in a special ordering. Also, I think there is a difference between just a regular configuration and what spring means by auto-configuration, right?

Comment: I don't think it's used on the class itself, rather the individual beans as the answer below points out. The `@EnabledAutoConfiguration` annotation simply instructs Spring to attempt to configure bean definitions that you'll need; as far as I know there is no such thing as an auto configuration vs. regular configuration.

Comment: @Mike It’s definitely used on the class itself, you can find this in the spring docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html (under 6.10 Multiple HttpSecurity). But it seems like the security module has developed some custom logic for this annotation that only affects the resulting filter chains and does not affect at all the bean creation time. But I can’t find a definitive statement on this.

Answer (score 1):

Put the `@Order(...)` annotations over the methods producing beans (next to the `@Bean` annotation). Make sure that they both have the same interface as a return type

Instead of providing exact `int` values you can also use [Ordered](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/Ordered.html) interface

Comment: This does not seem to fix the problem. The same exception occurs. I think the fact that the configuration has two beans of the same type isn't really relevant to the issue. I included it because that's the exact case that I was dealing with. I should have checked that before posting the question - my bad. Sorry for the confusion!